# Why do salt flakes start building up in a bottle of mineral water after it was first opened?

Tags: water

I noticed that mineral water with high mineralization doesn't have salt flakes floating on the bottom of the bottle on store shelves, but when I open one, after some time they start accumulating. Does it have something to do with decarbonation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility

Salt solubility decreases with decreasing pressure.

Answer (score 1):

It could be gases (oxygen or carbon dioxide) from the air, competing as solvents with the salts.  I know the reverse effect: adding salt tends to drive out gases.

I'm not sure whether this gas explanation is more significant than the pressure explanation.
But, you could do an experiment: briefly let the pressure out and then retighten the cap without letting fresh air enter, and see if the crystals still form.

Comment: They do, since the pressure falls.